# AngularJS & Google Visualization - Visibility of $scope variables (JS) on an HTML page using a state change handler (Google API)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-visualization

I'm working on a piece of code for web development where I have a page that is using a date range and a number range filter of the Google Visualization API. At the same time I'm making use of AngularJS throughout the page.

Now, my problem is as follows: I have a table with a certain amount of entries. When applying one of the filters, I would like the number of entries (== # of rows) to be shown somewhere on the HTML page.

My intent to realize this is by using the `getNumberOfRows()` method from the Google API and storing the result in a `$scope` variable to be used on the page, ideally to be updated every time one of the range filters change state.

I have added 3 listeners, one for clicks on table rows (using a `selectHandler()`) and one to handle state changes of the range filters (using a separate function `stateChangeHandler()`).

I'm storing the value in the variable `$scope.numberOfRowsShown`.

The whole thing works for the clicks (`selectHandler`). So when clicking a table row, I get the updated correct number of rows shown calling the variable on the HTML page with `{{numberOfRowsShown}}` (AngularJS).

Doing the exact same thing except calling the function and storing it to the variable `$scope.numberOfRowsShown` inside the `stateChangeHandler()` does give me the correct output in the console, but it doesn't let me access the variable by calling `{{numberOfRowsShown}}` anymore.

Any ideas?

Here's the JS code:

```
function selectHandler() {
    // this works!!
    $scope.numberOfRowsShown = table.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows();
};

function stateChangeHandler() {
    // this does not work..
    $scope.numberOfRowsShown = table.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows();
    // correct output in the console..
    console.log(table.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows());
};

// Setup listener to listen for clicks on table rows and process the selectHandler.
google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'select', selectHandler);

// Setup listeners for statechange in the slider range filters.
google.visualization.events.addListener(dateOfLastAccessFilter, 'statechange', stateChangeHandler);
google.visualization.events.addListener(timeSinceLastAccessFilter, 'statechange', stateChangeHandler);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured this out. All I needed to do was reload the table!